# Prove or disprove if $T$ be idempotent t-norm and $a\leq b$ then $T(a,b)=a$ for all $a,b\in[0,1]$?

Tags: normed-spaces

Let $T : [0, 1]\times [0, 1] \rightarrow [0, 1]$. A $t$-norm is a function $T$ with properties:

1. $ T (x, 1) = x$
2. If $y\leq z$ then $T(x,y)\leq T(x,z)$
3. $T (x, y) = T (y, x) $
4. $T (x, T (y, z)) = T (T (x, y), z) $

$T$ said to be a idempotent t-norm if for all $x\in[0,1]$, $T(x,x)=x$.

Prove or disprove:

> Let $T$ be idempotent t-norm. If $a\leq b$ then $T(a,b)=a$ (for all
> $a,b\in[0,1])$?

If we take example $T(x,y)=\min(x,y)$, obviously if $a\leq b$ then $T(a,b)=a$. Generally, if $T$ be idempotent t-norm and $a\leq b$ then prove or disprove $T(a,b)=a$?

I don't have an idea to prove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking a long time, I have an idea to prove it.

Let $a,b\in[0,1]$. Then,
$$
a=T(a,a)\leq T(a,b)\leq T(a,1)=a.
$$
So, I can conclude $T(a,b)=a$.